# Spark java.lang StackOverFlow Error When converting Custom class Object to DataSet

Tags: java, apache-spark

```
public class OuterClass implements Serializable {
int id;
ArrayList<InnerClass> listofInner;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int num) {
    this.id = num;
}

public ArrayList<InnerClass> getListofInner() {
    return listofInner;
}

public void setListofInner(ArrayList<InnerClass> list) {
    this.listofInner = list;
}

public static class InnerClass implements Serializable {
    String streetno;
    private List<InnerClass> children = new ArrayList<InnerClass>();

    public void setStreetno(String streetno) {
        this.streetno = streetno;
    }

    public String getStreetno() {
        return streetno;
    }

    public List<InnerClass> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<InnerClass> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

}

```
OuterClass us = new OuterClass();
    us.setId(111);
    //Inner
    OuterClass.InnerClass ic = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
    ic.setStreetno("My Street");

    ic.getChildren().add(new OuterClass.InnerClass());

ArrayList<OuterClass.InnerClass> ar = new ArrayList<OuterClass.InnerClass>();
    ar.add(ic);
    us.setListofInner(ar);


    //DF
    Encoder<OuterClass> outerClassEncoder = Encoders.bean(OuterClass.class);
    Dataset<OuterClass> ds = spark.createDataset(Collections.singletonList(us), outerClassEncoder);
```

In the above **InnerClass** class has property 
List children = new ArrayList(); this is a type of**InnerClass** list. Because of this when I am trying to covert this Custom Object to **Dataset**.  I am getting error

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl.equals(TypeVariableImpl.java:189).

If I remove the **children** property from InnerClass. It works fine.

So Any one please help me..:)

Comment: Watch out for recursion in `children`. Looks like Spark is checking objects for equality using reflection, so maybe two children are referencing each other, or maybe parent with children, and it gets stuck bouncing calls between them...

Comment: @Marco Bolis  how do I Watch out for recursion in children?. I am new for this

Comment: even we raised a ticket in spark https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19751